# Delete content inside Word Bookmark in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I'm working on an ASP C# project which has to hide sections of a bookmarked Word document that includes plenty of tables inside. The first approach we had consisted on deleting the parent element of each tag, which works but requires tagging lines that have no data in them and leaves the previous space open in the final document(as in, if a page has two sections and you delete the one above, you get half whitespace and the section below).

So what we're trying now is adding a bookmark for each document section and deleting it altogether. So far what we've tried to accomplish this (taken from [How to delete all contents inside a word document bookmark using C# and Open XML](http://debugitalready.blogspot.com.ar/2013/07/how-to-delete-all-contents-inside-word.html)) is

```
BookmarkStart myBookMarkStart = OpenWordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == myBookMarkName);
OpenXmlElement sibling = myBookMarkStart.NextSibling();
while (!(sibling is BookmarkEnd))
{
    var temp = sibling;
    sibling = sibling.NextSibling();
    temp.Remove();
}
```

However, this doesn't remove anything inside the bookmark start and its end.

Comment: [How to delete data or table within two bookmarks from word document using OpenXml in C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/98d89ece-bd9b-413f-8782-6ea3fc4d8b01/how-to-delete-data-or-table-within-two-bookmarks-from-word-document-using-openxml-in-c?forum=oxmlsdk)

Comment: That method assumes there's no other bookmark between the two and only deletes paragraphs.